# android with external usb nfc device

Tags: android, nfc, nfc-p2p

I have to make an app where I have to use external USB NFC device to read and write data to NFC tags and also p2p between that reader and android nfc phones.

I have a NFC device ACR1222L.
I also downloaded the android library from http://android.acs.com.hk/
The library comes with a demo project.

Now My problem is when I run the demo project in emulator and connect my pc with the device, the project runs and shows the first screen. But when I put any tag on the device, nothing happens.

Is there anything that I need to do to make the demo project work?
I also did not find any good documentation about how to make an external nfc device work with android. Does anyone know any good source or tutorial?

Comment: Are you seeing any light on the reader?

Comment: Add what buttons you've pressed and that the log says

Comment: In the emulator i only have 'list' and 'open' button enabled. if I click on them, nothing happens.

Comment: BTW, do I have to do anything special to detect the USB port from the emulator. I saw some web pages where it says emulator can not detect usb though they are kind of 2 years old.

Comment: Get a real device and go from there

Comment: yes. it works with the real device. thanks